# Can I use a single jumper wire to run to two outlets and two breakers?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

Situation: Have a jetted bathtub that requires 2 15A gfci outlets each to its own breaker. Problem only have one wire running into tub area (would have to tear up.newly installed floor to run another. Is it possible to use that single wire and connect two wires and run to the outlets and connect two wires to the other end of the wire (wire is approx 8 ft) and run those to the breaker box and attach to two gcfi breakers?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about home wiring

Comment: A perfect example of how migration in SE just never works right. User already (appropriately) cross-posted to DIY, then the migration happened afterwards, resulting in a duplicate.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact if the OP mentioned that it was cross-posted then that may have helped the process. It is the cross posting that causes these issues.